# Dynamic Content in Dynamic Tab (Angular, UI Bootstrap)

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap-tab

I'd like to use ng-include in the content of a dynamically generated tab using AngularJs and UI Bootstrap.

I have a Plunker here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/2mpbovsu2eDrUdu8t7SM?p=preview

```
<div id="mainCntr" style="padding: 20px;">
  <uib-tabset>
    <uib-tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" active="tab.active" disable="tab.disabled">
      <uib-tab-heading>
        {{tab.title}} <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign" ng-click="removeTab($index)"></i>
      </uib-tab-heading>
      {{tab.content}}
    </uib-tab>
  </uib-tabset>
</div>
```

JS Code:

```
$scope.addTab = function() {
    var len = $scope.tabs.length + 1;
    var numLbl = '' + ((len > 9) ? '' : '0') + String(len);

    var mrkUp = '<div>' +
        '<h1>New Tab ' + numLbl + ' {{foo}}</h1>' + 
        '<div ng-include="tab.tabUrl" class="ng-scope"></div>' +
        '</div>';

    $scope.tabs.push({title: 'Tab ' + numLbl, content: $compile(angular.element(mrkUp))($scope)});
}
```

In the Plunker, click the "Add Tab" button. It calls a function in $scope that pushes a new tab to the collection but passing in some dynamically generated content that includes a ng-include directive. The expected output is that the ng-include will be displayed inside of the tab content area.

Thanks

Comment: Your plunk is not working properly I think?

Comment: I could not get it to work. The plunk is just my attempt - hoping someone here can help me get it to work.

Comment: ...oh, now it's working. When I looked at it earlier, it was broken. Will take a look again.

Comment: Now that I think about it, you're doing $compile before pushing the tab. Consider putting a watch on your $scope.tabs that will run $compile AFTER you've pushed on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your Plunker you are using `ng-bind-html` which doesn't compile the HTML for you. You can create a new directive that does that for you.

Source code for `ng-bind-html`:

```
var ngBindHtmlDirective = ['$sce', '$parse', '$compile', function($sce, $parse, $compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    compile: function ngBindHtmlCompile(tElement, tAttrs) {
      var ngBindHtmlGetter = $parse(tAttrs.ngBindHtml);
      var ngBindHtmlWatch = $parse(tAttrs.ngBindHtml, function getStringValue(value) {
        return (value || '').toString();
      });
      $compile.$$addBindingClass(tElement);

      return function ngBindHtmlLink(scope, element, attr) {
        $compile.$$addBindingInfo(element, attr.ngBindHtml);

        scope.$watch(ngBindHtmlWatch, function ngBindHtmlWatchAction() {
          // we re-evaluate the expr because we want a TrustedValueHolderType
          // for $sce, not a string
          element.html($sce.getTrustedHtml(ngBindHtmlGetter(scope)) || '');
        });
      };
    }
  };
}];
```

Pick a name for the new directive, for example `compile-html`.

Replace `tAttrs.ngBindHtml` with `tAttrs.compileHtml` (or whatever name you picked).

You need to replace `$sce.getTrustedHtml` with `$sce.trustAsHtml`, or you will get `Error: [$sce:unsafe] Attempting to use an unsafe value in a safe context.`

Then you need to call `$compile`:

```
$compile(element.contents())(scope);
```

Full directive:

```
app.directive('compileHtml', ['$sce', '$parse', '$compile',
  function($sce, $parse, $compile) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      compile: function ngBindHtmlCompile(tElement, tAttrs) {
        var ngBindHtmlGetter = $parse(tAttrs.compileHtml);
        var ngBindHtmlWatch = $parse(tAttrs.compileHtml, function getStringValue(value) {
          return (value || '').toString();
        });
        $compile.$$addBindingClass(tElement);

        return function ngBindHtmlLink(scope, element, attr) {
          $compile.$$addBindingInfo(element, attr.compileHtml);

          scope.$watch(ngBindHtmlWatch, function ngBindHtmlWatchAction() {

            element.html($sce.trustAsHtml(ngBindHtmlGetter(scope)) || '');
            $compile(element.contents())(scope);
          });
        };
      }
    };
  }
]);
```

Usage:

```
<div compile-html="tab.content"></div>
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/TRYAaxeEPMTAay6rqEXp?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

My situation might not be as complex, so this simple solution works:

```
sdo.tabs:{
        data:[],
        active:0,
        reset: function(){
            var tabs = this.data;
            while( tabs.length > 0 ) {
                this.removeTab( tabs[tabs.length-1].child.name);
            }
            this.active = 0;
        },
        childExists: function( childName ) {
            var fromTheTop = this.data.length,
                parentName = ( this.active > 0 ? this.data[ this.active - 1 ].child.name : 'zero' );
            while( fromTheTop > this.active ) {
                var child = this.data[ fromTheTop-1 ].child;
                if( child && child.parent === parentName && child.name === childName ) return fromTheTop;
                fromTheTop--;
            }
            return false;
        },
        removeTab: function( name ) { // will remove any descendents of this tab as well, see recursive call near end
            var fromTheTop = this.data.length;
            while( fromTheTop > 0 ) {
                var tab = this.data[fromTheTop - 1];
                if( tab.child.name === name ) {
                    angular.element( '#'+name ).empty();
                    this.data.splice( fromTheTop - 1);
                    return;
                }
                if( tab.child.parent === name) this.removeTab( tab.child.name );
                fromTheTop--;
            };
        },
        /*
         * tab is string identifies tab but doesn't show in the UI
         * tempmlate is HTML template
         * scope is used to compile template
         * title is string or function for UI tab title, appears in the tab row
         */
        create: function( tab, template, scope, title ) {
            var childName = tab;
            var tabs = this.data;
            tab = this.childExists( childName );
            if( tab === false ) {
                tab = tabs.length + 1;
            } else { // recycling a tab, kill it & its descendents
                this.removeTab( childName );
            }
            tabs[tab-1] = {
                title:function(){
                    if( angular.isFunction(title) ) return title();
                    return title;
                },
                child: {
                    parent:( this.active > 0 ? this.data[ this.active - 1 ].child.name : 'zero' ), 
                    name:childName
                }                    
            };
            var ct = $timeout( function() {
                angular.element( '#'+tabs[tab-1].child.name ).html( $compile( template )( scope ) );
                sdo.tabs.active = tab;
                return; // return nothing to avoid memory leak
            });
            scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
                $timeout.cancel( ct );
            });
            return ct; // ct is a promise
        }
    }
```

HTML is

```html
<uib-tabset active="tabs.active">
    <uib-tab index='0' heading="{{title}}">
        <ng-view></ng-view>
    </uib-tab>
    <uib-tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs.data track by tab.child.name" heading="{{tab.title()}}" index='$index+1' >
        <div id="{{tab.child.name}}"></div>
    </uib-tab>
</uib-tabset>
```

In my case the first tab is populated by the Angular router, which is why the tab array is one index out from `tabs.active`